# how to pass the data to other page after validate the page?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have finish my validation form and everything working fine, but I have problem on how to transfer the data from the form to another .php page which is the process page.

I`m currently refer from this site for form validation code
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required

*myform*

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" id="form">

       <fieldset>
                <td>Name</td>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name = "nama">
                    </input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                  </label>
                  <br>
                   <p>Gender</p>
                   <p>
                    Male</p><input type="radio" name= "gender" value="Male" >
                    <br>

                    <input name= "gender" type="radio" value="Female">
                Female<br></input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>

                  <br>
                  <td>Contact No</td>
                  <label>
                    <input type="text" name= "contact">
                    </input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $contactErr;?></span>
                  </label>

                  <br>
                  <td>Address</td>
                  <label>
                    <textarea name= "address"></textarea>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $addressErr;?></span>
                  </label>
                  <br>
                <td>Email</td>
                  <label>
                    <input type="text" name= "email"></input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                  </label>
                  <br>
                  <td>Account Name</td>
                  <label>
                    <input type="text" name= "account"></input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $accountErr;?></span>
                  </label>
                  <br>
                  <td>Password</td>
                  <label>
                    <input type="password" name= "password"></input>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
                  </label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="button" value="Cancel"onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">


                </fieldset>
              </form>
```

*process.php*

```
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sport');

$nama=$_POST["nama"];
$gender=$_POST["gender"];
$contact=$_POST["contact"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$account=$_POST["account"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO sport(name, gender, contact, address, email, account, password, eventtype) VALUES ('$nama' , '$gender', '$contact' , '$address', '$email', '$account', '$password', '')"; 

$query=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$query)
{
    echo "Fail to register";
}
else
{
header('Location:login_success.html');  
}

?>
```

How do I pass the data after I validate the form to process.php and execute the sql query so I store the data into the database.
Supposedly we just put the target page in , but the code required me to use `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link you have provided that they have used a server side validation instead of doing the server side validation try to do a client side validation by using the JavaScript or jQuery.

you can check the simplest way of doing the JavaScript validation  here :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js

or you can try this by using any jquery library for form validation:

http://formvalidator.net/

for demo : http://formvalidator.net/#reg-form

Comment: @Newbie if it help you so please accept as an answer.

Comment: JavaScript validation work like a champ and simple. But, how I do multiple validation using the script? I try play around with the if statement, but it just validate the first statement

Comment: try elseif for each field validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is pointing to **itself**, so I'll assume the validation code is above the snippet you posted (as shown in the link you provided).

When you send a *POST HTTP request* to PHP, it'll store form data in an associative array at superglobals `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`. The script referenced on "form action" is the "owner" of `$_POST` content, meaning other non-related scripts won't be able to access it.
To solve it, you should `require` or `include` the process.php script into your form, so it can manipulate `$_POST` content as well **(beware your code flux!)**.

Please, note this is just to answer what you're asking, but it's **not the best way to solve your problem**. Form validation processes are better approached client-side with asynchronous methods such as AJAX as you can see in this [tutorial](http://michaelsoriano.com/how-to-ajax-validate-forms/). Also, check out PHP form good practices [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6194).